# Build configuration for llvm-config to include correct .inc files

Tags: haskell, clang, llvm, ghc

I am currently working on a project that requires [`llvm-hs`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/llvm-hs) package. Since this package only supports up to `llvm-9`, while I do have `llvm-13` installed on my machine for other projects, I built `llvm-9` from source on my machine, and added its `bin` to `PATH`. However, it seems that when the C compiler was resolving the `.inc` files included in `llvm-9`'s header files (e.g. `#include "llvm/IR/Attributes.inc"` in `llvm/IR/Attributes.h`), it incorrectly used those from `/usr/include` rather than those from the built `llvm-9`.

My observation is that `GHC` uses `llvm-config` to determine the relevant compiler arguments. On this machine, `llvm-config-9 --includedir` gives me `{llvm-9-src-dir}/llvm/include`, which is missing `{llvm-9-src-dir}/build/include/` (where the correct `.inc` files are located). How should I build my `llvm-9` such that `llvm-config` gives the correct `includedir`? The `cmake` configurations I used for building my `llvm-9` was:

```
  cmake ../llvm \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/llvm90 \
    -DLLVM_BUILD_LLVM_DYLIB=ON \
    -DLLVM_LINK_LLVM_DYLIB=ON \
    -DLLVM_INSTALL_UTILS=ON \
    -DLLVM_ENABLE_RTTI=ON \
    -DLLVM_ENABLE_FFI=ON \
    -DLLVM_BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
    -DLLVM_ENABLE_DOXYGEN=OFF \
    -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang
```